# ng-repeat not getting the values

Tags: angularjs, json

I have got two radio buttons and textarea here where I have to bind the ng-repeat data to it from mysql database. So how can I do it.

```
    <label>Gender:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender"ng-value = "x.gender" ng-model="stdCtrl.gender" value="male" required>Male</input>
        <input type="radio" name="gender"ng-value = "x.gender" ng-model="stdCtrl.gender" value="female" required>Female</input>



    <label>Home-Address</label>
        <textarea name = "address"
            ng-required = "true"
            ng-value = "x.address"
            ng-model = "stdCtrl.address"
            class = "form-control"
            placeholder = "PresentAddress"
            row = "10" cols = "50" ></textarea>
```

Now the problem is I couldnt get the textarea value from my url data where Im bringing the details into the controller. Here is my url decoded data.

```
$scope.StudentCtrl = function(){
alert("bye");
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
   }
 var fType = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($scope.StudentCtrl()['data']));
console.log(fType);
$scope.fType = fType;
```

Comment: $scope.fType is an array ? and you want to bind it with textarea?

Comment: Bind data to textArea ? Please be more specific

Comment: okay, im getting the data as json object from url and then decoding it in a $scope variable and then Im using ng-value to bind it back to its own text fields but what happens is all the text fields except these two are binding well. I have problem with this textarea where I include customers address from the form and the gender error.

Comment: Show your object `fType`. What in console?

Comment: 0 "3"
1 "Pietersen"
2 "Kevin"
3 "male"
4 "k7@gmail.com"
5 "Kevin Bhajbhai"
6 "Bhai"
7 "1999-02-02"
8 "MEGASYSTEMS INC\nSUITE 5A...RAM\nTUCSON AZ 85705\nUSA"
9 "58.5"
10 "60.25"
$$hashKey
"object:3"
address "MEGASYSTEMS INC\nSUITE 5A...RAM\nTUCSON AZ 85705\nUSA"
birthday "1999-02-02"
email "k7@gmail.com"
fathername "Kevin Bhajbhai"
firstname "Pietersen"
gender "male"
lastname "Kevin"
mothername "Bhai"
studentid "3"
tenth "58.5"
twelfth "60.25"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for the textarea element to bind the ng-repeat data.

```
<textarea name = "address"
                ng-required = "true"
                ng-bind = "x.address"
                ng-model = "stdCtrl.address"
                class = "form-control"
                placeholder = "PresentAddress"
                row = "10" cols = "50" ></textarea>
```

So by adding ng-bind directive you will be able to bind the data from ng-repeat and also it returns the way how you typed it at first part.